# Using loop to draw line

Tags: java

I'm supposed to draw this in Java

[image]

This is what I have so far:

`DrawPanel.java`

```
package drawpaneltest;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int d = 0;
        while (d < 301) {
            g.drawLine(0, d, width, height);
            d += 15;
        }
    }
}
```

---

`DrawPanelTest.java`

```
package drawpaneltest;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawPanelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel); // add the panel to the frame 
        application.setSize(250, 250); // set the size of the frame
        application.setVisible(true); // make the frame visible 
    }
}
```

The above code sample currently displays the following:

[image: Code sample window]

What did I missed out? How should I add the curved line and the vertical line?

Comment: **Hint:** The "curved" line is not a curved line, it's actually edged.

Comment: There are no curved lines at all on this picture, just straight lines.

Comment: Here's how to draw that picture on paper http://www.wikihow.com/Draw-a-Parabolic-Curve-(a-Curve-with-Straight-Lines)

Comment: @TassosBassoukos right bottom corner seems like curved

Comment: @HRgiger bottom right corner (⇲) looks like a plain acute angle to me...

Comment: @TassosBassoukos thank you for visual support:) I still can see lines getting curved when they get closer to right bottom. And I am ready to argue for that!(joking)

Comment: `What did I missed out?` - A line has a starting point and an ending point. You only change the starting point and always have the ending fixed. For the starting point the y variable changes. For the ending point the x variable changes.

Comment: @HRgiger it's a [visual illusion](http://www.weirdoptics.com/the-hering-illusion/) :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also change the `to` coordinates (`d` replacing `width`):

```
g.drawLine(0, d, d, height);
```

Comment: Your solution will generate parallel lines.

Comment: That wouldn't draw lines to the side of the screen.

Comment: Oups, yes indeed. Thanks @Flown for noticing. Just corrected the line (hope I did not miss it this time).

Comment: @austinwernli, after my edit 3 min ago, it does reproduce the expected result

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
package drawpaneltest;


import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int x1 = 0, y1 = 0,
            x2 = 0, y2 = height;
        while (y1 < height) {
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            y1+=15;                 //You should modify this if
            x2+=15;                 //it's not an equal square (like 250x250)
        }
    }
 }
```

And then it will do this:
[image]

However in JPanel, coordinate (0,0) begin on the left top corner,
not on left bottom corner as usual.
And it still can not do well on a (m x n) squares, you have to do a lot more than this.